# Why are the contour lines of a sphere more spread out near the equator, if a sphere is homogeneous?

Tags: geometry

I realize that this question may not be a formal as you're used too, but I'd appreciate it if you'd bear with me.

So, I have a conceptual question about the contour lines of a sphere (in this case $\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}$, the top half of a sphere.  It is not so hard to follow the actual computations.

But the lines are concentrated towards the edges of the sphere along the x - y axis.

[image]

Since the curvature of the sphere is the same at all points, this seems to imply that the sphere is 'steeper' in that region than towards the top, which (I don't think) is true, considering you could rotate the sphere however you like and be left with and 'identical' shape.

Thanks to anyone who can shed some light on this!

Comment: Of course it's steeper at the base than at the top --- think about climbing a hemispherical mountain, how hard it would be to get started, how much easier once you get near the top.

Comment: In fact, that's exactly what I was thinking when I thought I understood it at first.  But since you could rotate it at any time... wait I GOT IT (*just* now)! (Mabye.)  Does this mean the the steepness is just relative to the xy plane (in *this* case) and that theoretically you could compute the contour lines for any plane and hmmm... I dunno .. following that project it onto the xy plane (or render it in 3 dimensions?) @everyone Thanks!

Comment: @GerryMyerson I kinda figured out the basic answer trying to answer your comment.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a non-rigorous answer: the curvature of the sphere is the same at every point. But the places where the surface of the sphere is "steepest" in the $z$-direction *depends on how you're holding the sphere with respect to the $z$-direction*.

---

For my own, and anyone else's, reference, here is the *Mathematica* code for the picture I added:

```
Plot3D[Sqrt[9 - x^2 - y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 10, PlotPoints -> 5, 
 MaxRecursion -> 5, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False]
```

Comment: Thanks, that does a great job of illustrating the question.